# Apparent Confidence Interval Discrepancy in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would really appreciate your help with this discrepancy that I am not able to explain.

If I go about finding the 95% confidence interval of a set of data by first finding the standard deviation/mean, I am getting a different answer than if I use the Data Analysis Tool --> Descriptive Statistics --> Confidence Level.

For example, for the following data set (n = 16):

14, 9, 11, 9, 14, 10, 13, 14, 15, 13, 11, 11, 10, 14, 11, 13.

```
stdev = 1.966
average = 12 
count = 16

=confidence.norm(0.05,1.966,16) = **0.9635**
```

HOWEVER,

When this set of data is plugged into the "Descriptive Statistics" Tool, I receive a "Confidence Level (95.0%) = **1.0478**"

Are these two things measuring separate variables that I am not noticing? How should I be interpreting this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The discrepancy seems to be the result between the use of a t-distribution (Tool) instead of a normal distribution (Function). Instead try:

```
=CONFIDENCE.T(0.05,1.966,16)
```

That being said, `1.966` is not the true standard deviation either, but based on a sample set of data. I assume you either used `STDEV.S()` or `STDEV()`. Instead, if your data is not representing just a piece of sample data but rather your entire dataset, use `STDEV.P()`.

Comment: I understand; thank you very much! For further clarification, given that this set of data represents the entire population, it would make sense to use STDEV.P(). At the same time though, however, since the standard deviation is not known and is being estimated from the data, would CONFIDENCE.T() be more appropriate than CONFIDENCE.NORM()? Can you expand how you go about choosing one over the other?